# Using Queries with Eloquent Query Builder

Tags: eloquent, query-builder

everyone:
Id like to know how can I write a MySQL and execute it directly with the Query Builder. Let's say something easy, like `"SELECT name FROM customers WHERE age < '23' AND city LIKE '%Carolina';"`.

I'd like can use this query directly, no with methods, just pass the query as it is, and get the results. Is it possible?

Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. There are quite some methods available on the [`DB`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.php) facade. In your case, a simple `DB::select()` should do the trick:

```
DB::select('SELECT name FROM customers WHERE age < ? AND city LIKE ?', [23, '%Carolina']);
```

The second argument of `DB::select()` contains the parameters you pass to the query. Passing them this way prevents an sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you vey much. You really helped me.